# Chrome Extension with XMLHttpRequest slow at launch

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest

At the moment I am developing a Google Chrome Extension in which I have to fetch data from a server. I am doing this with an XMLHttpRequest and all is going well, except for the fact when I launch Google Chrome and immediately click my extension, it won't open until the XMLHttpRequest is completed. The request is sent to a rather slow server, that's where the problem is. But is there a way in which you might run the XMLHttpRequest in another thread or does Google Chrome give you another way to fetch data from a server that runs in the background so I can open my extension while it's still getting it's data from the server?

Maybe good to know, the XMLHttpRequest runs in the background page, not the popup page.

Comment: All requests are asynchronous, so this sounds like a UI issue related to the extension framework. What does "it won't open" mean? That the popup doesn't show? Are you clicking an extension icon in the toolbar or in the address bar?

Comment: I changed the asynchronous parameter from false to true, now it seems to work. By "it won't open" I meant that the popup wouldn't show up until the request was finished.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Strange that the async param was set to false. Asynchrony is usually the default. Synchronous XHRs are a bit of a hack. Also, if you put in a real answer and mark it as accepted, this question will provide more help to future extension developers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the Asynchronous parameter has to be set to true.